# Problem with probability in Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have an homogeneous Markov Chain with $S=\{A,B\}$ and the following transition matrix:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
&A &B \\
\hline
A & 0.7 & 0.3\\
B & 0.2 & 0.8\\
\end{array}$$

I'm asked the probability of being twice in a row in state $A$, knowing that the process started in state $B$, which I interpreted as $P [X_{n+1}=A,X_n=A|X_0=B],n=1,2,\ldots$ .

I separated the possibilities, through $P_{BA}\times P_{AA} + P_{BB} \times P_{BA} \times P_{AA} + \ldots$ , but there will be cases missing (the process can go to $A$ and get back to $B$ without being twice in a row in $A$), and doing this already adds to a value bigger than $1$.

I'm tempted to say that this probability equals $1$, since that this ocurrence is supposed to happen somewhere in the process, but I do not know any way to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(X)$ be the probability of visiting state $A$ twice in a row assuming we start in state $X$. Then we want to solve for $P(B)$ where:

$P(B) = .2P(A) + .8P(B)$

$P(A) = .7 + .3P(B)$

This resolves to $P(B) = 1$.